# Error while accessing the older branch in Sourcetree

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

I am working in a Project and created many different branch. If I load the old branch throws error as `./src/polyfils.ts`. I have no idea what is failed. The current branch is working in the same situation.

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5IOK.jpg)

I am using

> Angular CLI 8.3.19
>  Node 12.4.0

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Before you run your code try to run

```
git reset --hard origin/your-branch-name // the branch you just check out to get fresh version
```

Also check to see if polyfill is exist or not in your src folder